# Howto size a control in a ToolStripControlHost-item?

Tags: c#, user-controls, size, menustrip, toolstripcontrolhost

i have litte problem here.

I just made a `UserControl` for Undo/Redo like in Visual Studio.
I wanted to add it to my `MenuStrip` by an `ToolStripControlHost`.

The problem is, that the control is too small. It´s width is just about 100, but should be 200.
How can i size it? `Size` property doesn´t change anything. `AutoSize` has lots of issues because of changing controls, `Dock` doesn´t change anything ... I don´t know what i could do :-/

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to set the MinimumSize of your UserControl?

Comment: I don´t know exactly... the project was cancelled shortly after my post :-/ But i think i tried it. and it didn´t work..

Comment: This worked for me when I needed to fix the size of a control that was not being scaled for high DPI properly.